# On Bohr-MollerupTheorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, special-functions

In http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Bohr-MollerupTheorem.html, Bohr-Mollerup Theorem is given where it is stated that $\Gamma$ function is the unique log convex function that satisfies $\phi(x+1)=x\phi(x)$ for every $x\in\Bbb R$ with $\phi(1)=1$. Why is log convexity important? What are some other candidate functions if we drop log convexity(apart from the factorial function itself or some of its clever scaled version)?

I looking for a solution of form $\int_{0}^t f(x)dx=\phi(t)$ rather than $\int_{0}^\infty f(x,t)dx=\phi(t)$. $\Gamma$ function is of latter form.

Comment: Why do people keep downvoting this and @HansScundal's answer?

Comment: Take $(1+\sin(2\pi z))\Gamma(z)$. Or multiply $\Gamma$ by any 1-periodic function.

Comment: [I made a silly misstatement in a comment, which I have deleted]

Answer (score 1):

Take any function on $[0, 1)$ and extend it by the functional equation.

Comment: Let $f(x)=x^{100}+x^2+1$ which clearly takes values in $\Bbb R$ where $x\in\Bbb[0,1)$. How will you extend this?

Comment: Well, $F(1.5) = 0.5 F(0.5) = 0.5 f(0.5);$ $F(2.7) = 1 F(1.7) = 0.7 f(0.7),$ and so on. What's so unclear about this?

Comment: just not used to this way of thinking, let me think about this. So what is $F$ explicitly?

Comment: $$F(x) = f(\{x\}) \prod_{i=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} (x-i).$$

Answer (score 0):

The function

$$
g(x)
=
\begin{cases}
\Gamma(x), & x - \lfloor x\rfloor < 1/2\\
2\Gamma(x), & x - \lfloor x\rfloor \geq 1/2
\end{cases}
$$

satisfies $g(x+1) = g(x)$ and $g(1) = 1$.

Comment: I edited the layout of your answer. If you don't like it, feel free to re-edit or roll back to the original version.